# ISQL + MSSQL Server (Linux) - Problem with Insert and Select when using accented characters

Tags: sql-server, unixodbc, isql

I have a database where a table has texts with accented characters.

Example: João, César, Pão, Açucar (words in language ptBR).

When I do a query using the SQL Management Studio or DBeaver, for example, the contents of the column is displayed correctly. However, the same query instruction, when executed through ISQL, does not display the accented characters, instead, displays a question mark.
Example: Jo?o, C?sar, P?o, A?ucar

I've tried the procedures below:

- Change the LANG of the section to en_US.ISO88591 (without success)
- Change the LC_TYPE to POXIS/C (without success)
- Make the connection in the ISQL using parameter -len_US.ISO88591 (without success)

Important:

- The same query, when performed through the SQLCMD, display the characters correctly.
- I can't depend only on the SQLCMD, because some servers only have the ISQL

Someone has already gone through this situation?
There is a palliative or bug fix to solve this behavior?

EDIT: Steps to reproduce the problem

```
::::Statement to create database::::

CREATE DATABASE [dbaccess]
ON PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'dbaccess', FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaccess.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
FILEGROUP [DBACCESS_DATA] DEFAULT
( NAME = N'dbaccess_data', FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaccess_data.ndf' , SIZE = 500MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 50MB ), 
FILEGROUP [DBACCESS_IDX] 
( NAME = N'dbaccess_idx', FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaccess_idx.ndf' , SIZE = 100MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10MB )
COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
GO


::::Statement to create table::::
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1(T1_CPOC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT T1_T1_CPOC_DF DEFAULT '                    ')

::::Statement to insert data::::
INSERT INTO dbo.T1(T1_CPOC) VALUES ('çÇáÁéÉíÍêÊãÃõÕ')

:::: Statement to connect to database from ISQL::::
isql -v <dsn_name> <user> <password>

:::: Query and Result  ::::
SQL> select * from T1
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| T1_CPOC             | D_E_L_E_T_| R_E_C_N_O_          | R_E_C_D_E_L_        |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ??????????????      |           | 1                   | 0                   |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I am grateful for the support of the community!

Comment: I would give a try with local set to en_US.UTF-16, according to this it seems to be the better supported encoding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/known-issues-in-this-version-of-the-driver?view=sql-server-2017
Eventually it will be easy to get support if you follow the guidelines and include a full consistent code, i.e. create table, insert etc in the SQL so anyone who has a linux installed ms-sql server machine can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: @P.Lion,

Thank you for your contribution!

I do not use the UTF-16 locale, since in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat?view=sql-server-2017) there is an explicit guidance to remove a possible unixODBC version of this codepage.

The ISO88591 codepage is ideal for my application as it is similar to the CP1252 for Windows.

I await new directions from community!

Best regards!

Comment: @DanSigolo You're trying to insert Unicode characters and yet your strings are ASCII. Use Unicode instead. Your fields should be `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`. Unicode literals start with `N`, ie `INSERT INTO dbo.T1(T1_CPOC) VALUES (N'çÇáÁéÉíÍêÊãÃõÕ')`. The guide doesn't say anything about avoiding Unicode it simply says you need to remove any leftover libraries from earlier versions. The script files should be UTF8 too to avoid mangling or losing text when the text editor saves the data.

Comment: @DanSigolo Unicode just works in SQL Server by the way and StackOverflow is the proof. I know I can write Αυτό Εδώ and get it to display properly because it's an ASP.NET application storing strings in `nvarchar` fields in SQL Server. Strings in ASP.NET and Windows are UTF16 so there's no chance of conversion issues. *Your code* though shows that different codepages were used between client and server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,

Thank you for your feedback!
Unfortunately I can't use NVARCHAR type, because the system does not work with this type!

For the time being, I wonder if it is possible to have ISQL (insert and return) the "correct" values.
I can't use the outline approach in my application, unfortunately.

Remembering:
- Through SQLCMD, for example, everything works as expected
- Using a client to insert and query, like DBeaver, everything works as expected

Comment: @DanSigolo `the system does not work with this type` that sounds rather dubious. That's not some special-case type, that's available in all big databases since the 90s (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase). That's how Oracle running on eg HP-UX stores Unicode characters.What system doesn't work and why? If it has a bug, it needs to be fixed. If what you say is true, it can't work with any database that uses Unicode

Comment: @DanSigolo in any case, the system *can* work - all drivers, in all languages *translate* database types to those used by the language. Most of them can also translate between codepages too. Are you using an ODBC driver? Which one, in which language?